# Dispatching a click event on htmlElement with an embedded script only works on first of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, click

I have a chrome extension that injects an embedded javascript file into a webpage, and then attempts to 'click' multiple elements on the page. HTMLElements are passed one a time as a 'selection' to a 'clickSelected' method. The method creates a new click event, dispatches it on the selection and then performs a blocking check.

When I call the 'clickSelected' method two/three times on a webpage, the first element for which it is called registers a click in the UI (seen via a visible button response), but not the second or third time. Inspecting logs, everything seems like it should work, but no UI action happens. Creating separate events did not help, and I am able to click the second or third selections, but again, only one element at a time registers.

Here is the method I am using:

```
clickSelected(selection: HTMLElement) { 
        let click = new Event('click');
        selection.dispatchEvent(click);
        let didClick = selection.dispatchEvent(click);
        console.log("was it unblocked?", didClick)
     }
```

Any thoughts or ideas as to why this is happening would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: 1) Add `{bubbles:true}` to event config. 2) Debug the site's event listeners in devtools and find the difference between a real click and a simulated one. 3) Try selection.click().